# How do i use my parser as a multiline parser in fluentbit?

Tags: spring-boot, logging, docker-compose, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to parse the logs i get from my spring-boot application with fluentbit in a specific way.

**parsers.conf**

```
[PARSER]
    Name   springboot
    Format regex
    regex   ^(?<time>[^ ]+)( )+(?<level>[^ ]+)( )+(?<pid>\d+)( )+---( )+\[( )*(?<thread>[^\]]+)\]( )+(?<logger>[^ ]+)( )+:( )+(?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key   timestamp
    Time_Format   %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
    Time_Keep   On
    rule "start_state" "/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+Z)/" "start_state"
```

**fluent-bit.conf**

```
SERVICE]
    flush       1
    log_level   error
    parsers_file parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name    forward
    Listen  0.0.0.0
    port    24224
    Multiline On
    Parser_Firstline springboot

[FILTER]
    Name         parser
    Match        spring-boot.*
    Key_Name     log
    Parser       springboot

[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host  elasticsearch
    Port  9200
    # this is a depenency to deployment-steps regarding index lifecycle management (ilm)
    Index fluent-bit-spring-test
    Logstash_Format Off
    Retry_Limit     no_limits
    #tls               On
    #http_user         elastic
    #http_passwd       xyz
    Trace_Error On
    Suppress_Type_Name On

[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  *
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.5"

volumes:
  log-data:
    driver: local
  opensearch-data1:

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      # allow running with low disk space
      - cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    networks:
      - elastic
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:9200/_cat/health | grep -q green" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    restart: unless-stopped
  
  fluentbit:
    container_name: fluentbit
    networks:
      - elastic
      - opensearch-net
    image: fluent/fluent-bit
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/fluent-bit.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf
      - ./fluentd/parsers.conf:/fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
    ports:
      - 24224:24224
      - 24224:24224/udp

  spring-boot-test:
    container_name: spring-boot-test
    build: ./spring-boot
    depends_on:
      - fluentbit
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        tag: spring-boot.access

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:9.2.1
    container_name: grafana
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - elastic
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/

networks:
  elastic: 
    name: elastic
    driver: bridge
  opensearch-net:
```

If i start the services with `docker-compose up` i get the following error message from the fluentbit service: `[2023/05/15 11:32:38] [error] [config] forward: unknown configuration property 'multiline'. The following properties are allowed: tag_prefix, unix_path, unix_perm, buffer_chunk_size, and buffer_max_size.`

Do i have a mistake? Because in the fluentbit documentation it says that i can use the Multiline prefix in the fluent-bit.conf.

imo, the error makes no sense, but i am new to this technology..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start the whole set of app and fluent-bit to verify the fluent-bit configuration.

Just have a plain binary installation of fluent-bit on your machine and use `-c` to verify before launching with the application / service that you need.

Back to the error message that you have, your `forward` INPUT has 02 incorrect configuration parameters

- Multiline
- Parser_Firstline

You can refer to [the documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/forward) and fix them.